# Background images defined using "style" attributes not showing in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background-image

In my website i wanted to provide 'copy protection' for images by defining them as backgrounds. Its working perfectly on Chrome, Safari and FF. But on IE the background images are not showing. You can check out the site [www.kettik.com](http://www.kettik.com).

The approach i followed was something like this. Since the images are from the DB, i cannot define the background properties inside the css class and have to use the 'style' attribute to define it.

```
 <div class="contentItemCover" style="clear:both;">
     <img src="/images/sitegfx/spacer.gif", style = "background: url('xyz') no-repeat;">
 </div>

.contentItemCover img {
   width: 600px;
   height: 290px;
   padding: 0px !important;
 }
```

Is there any way to work around this issue in IE ? Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in IE8 on Windows. What exactly is the issue? Can you show an example image URL that doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention the IE version. The images are not showing for me in IE7. And pretty much all the pages in my site have the issue. I havent tested this on IE 8 yet. FYI: My machine is a Mac, so i use Wine to test the rendering on IE. IE8 does not work on Wine.

Comment: I hope you realize that this technique will only stop the most inexperienced noobs. There is really little point in "protecting" anything you put online.

Comment: one thing that I've encountered with background images in IE is that IE will be more strict about whitespace within the `background` style definition.  So, while the example above looks fine, you may want to check what's really getting rendered, and make sure there're spaces are the parenthesis, etc

Comment: A sample page with just a single image. http://www.kettik.com/go/Asia/China/Beijing/photos/115

Comment: @Diodeus: yes i'am aware that anyone with little knowledge of html/css can find a way around the protection. But since implementing this feature was pretty straight forward (until this IE issue), i figured its worth it.

Comment: @bdukes: Thanks, i will check the spaces. Any other such pointers would be helpful.

Comment: @saravanak: Anyone with knowledge of the Print Screen key can get around it :) I would argue not to do this at all because the benefits are minimal at best, and you lose the ability to add the `alt` or `title` attributes.

Comment: @thirtydot: Im able to add alt/title attributes without issue http://www.kettik.com/go/Asia/India/Ladakh/stories/48. Yes, if im not able to find any workaround for this issue then i'll go about removing the feature from my site. Want to explore all the alternatives first.

Comment: @saravanak: I didn't look at your code well enough; you're of course right, you can still add the attributes.

Comment: @Everyone: Take a look at this smugmug site http://site.nvisiblephoto.com/gallery/3533232_FBs5G#346212308_DefPs. This is the functionality im looking for. Its pretty late now here in India, i'll examine their code tomorrow to see what im doing wrong.

Comment: @saravanak: [It works in IE7 for me](http://i.imgur.com/b7xf6.png). Someone please upvote this comment so others can see it easily.

Comment: @thirtydot: Wow.. Thanks so much. Do the other pages display properly as well ?? Maybe its some rendering issue in Wine. Guess its time for me to scour for a proper windows machine to do my testing. Sorry for wasting everyone's time with this non-issue.

Comment: @saravanak: As far as I can tell, the three pages on your site that you have linked within this question look fine in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="/images/sitegfx/spacer.gif", style = "background: url('xyz') no-repeat;">
```

Have you tried removing that comma?

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to say that this "method" of protecting images has a few flaws.
You could easily right-click it and say "save background image..." (in IE) and in FF you can "view background image" and then save it anyway.  or, you could simply screenshot it. I would advise watermarking images.

Comment: And people can't print it (since almost everyone has "Don't print backgrounds" turned on, which is the default setting)

Comment: If they can save the image, they can print it easily. There's really no fool-proof method to preventing someone form getting an image, especially if they want it.